# How to delay TFS build until after check-ins are complete

Tags: linux, git, tfs

The problem:  Syncing Git to TFS using a scheduled script.  I need to be able to delay TFS build until after the check-ins are complete.  TFS usually wants to kick off when there is a check-in, but the script will be checking in en mass, and not until all other check-ins are complete.

What I'm looking for:

1. How can I delay the TFS build until all check-ins are complete?
2. If #1 can't be solved, how can I kick off a build from linux?

I would like the git sync script to kick off a TFS build if there were actually and changes.  I know I can do this from Winodws, but git sits in Linus for us.

Answer (score 0):

In your Build Definition, select the radio option titled **Rolling builds**, making sure to specify the minimum length of time that should elapse between builds.

EDIT: This may also be known as a 'Quiet-Period' to some

What that will do is similar to the **Continuous Integration** option, except that builds will not be queued any closer together than *X* minutes:

> **Build**: delay is set for 10 minutes
>   **Dev A**: commit at 13:00
>   **Build**: kicks off, finishes at 13:05
>   **Dev B**: commit at 13:07
>   **Build**: ...zzzzzz.....
>   **Dev C**: commit at 13:16
>   **Build**: GO TIME

Comment: Should that be 'delay is set for 5 minutes'?

Comment: @Ray Hayes - no, because the time span you specify is the *minimum* amount of time that must elapse between individual builds. I'll update the post to make that more clear

Comment: oh, I get it.  The build of Dev A finished at 13:05 not started 5 minutes after the commit.  The way we have commit/build delay is that there is a "quiet-period" after commits, before the the build starts (5 minutes) so that developers who can't do 'single-commit' of changes don't trigger the CI build when they're missing changes/files.